# How to use nested variable from Jenkinsfile in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkinsfile I have environment name specified as environment variable:

```
environment {
   WORK_ENV = 'DEV'
}
```

In my Ansible scripts I have variable:

```
postfix:
  DEV: temp
  TEST: test
```

So now depending on the value of the WORK_ENV variable the postfix should change.

I need to have equivalent of this opperation in Ansible:

```
{{ postfix.{{ WORK_ENV }} }}
```

I know this line won't work so I'm looking for a workaround - any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I've tried lookup:

```
{{ lookup('vars', 'postfix_' + work_env) }}
```

And I have my vars like this (would prefere to use previous way):

```
postfix_DEV: "temp"
postfix_UAT1: "TEST"
```

It kind of works, but the output is wrong...

[image]

Comment: You can pass it as a variable to the `ansible-playbook` execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it worked when I used:

```
- name: Run SQL scripts
  win_shell: |
    cd "{{ package_unzip_dest }}"
    Write-Output "Running script {{ item }}.sql"
    sqlcmd -S {{ server }} -U {{ db_user }} -P {{ db_password }} -i {{ item }}.sql -d {{ data_base }}_{{ lookup('vars', 'postfix_' + work_env) | to_nice_yaml | regex_replace('- ', '') }}
  with_items: "{{ scripts }}"
  vars:
    postfix_DEV: temp
    postfix_UAT1: TEST
```

Without using to_nice_yaml I've had a problem with unicode output.

Answer (score 0):

If your var really is available in your jenkins env and you are running the playbook from there, you can try the following which will [lookup the value in your env vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/env.html)

```
{{ postfix[lookup('env', 'WORK_ENV')] }}
```

If this does not work in your scenario, you can pass an extra var to your playbook as suggested by @Matt Schuchard in the comments above.

Comment: What is the 'env' part here?

Comment: Answer edited with link to env lookup documentation.